# find() on object array is only finding the first value, not specific object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of 4 objects that populate a dropdown menu. Everytime I change the menu, it is supposed to take the value of the dropdown menu and map the location using its lat and long.

I am using the find method to search through the array, but it is only returning the values from the first object in the array, no matter what is selected. Any help?

```
var MagicKingdom = {description: "Magic Kingdom Park", latitude: 28.417713, 
     longitude: -81.581206}
var Epcot = {description: "Epcot", latitude: 28.374786, longitude: 
     -81.549396}
var AnimalKingdom = {description: "Disney's Animal Kingdom Theme Park", 
     latitude: 28.359792, longitude: -81.591316}
var HollywoodStudios = {description: "Disney's Hollywood Studios'", 
     latitude: 28.357568, longitude: -81.558275}

var populate = document.getElementById("locationSelect");
var locations = [MagicKingdom, Epcot, AnimalKingdom, HollywoodStudios];

var locationSelection = function(){
    var selected = document.getElementById("locationSelect");
    console.log(selected.value);
    var svalue = function(){
        return selected.value;
    }

    console.log(svalue());

    var locationSelected = locations.find(svalue);
    console.log(locationSelected.description);
}
```

Here are the return values:

```
p2.js:42 Magic Kingdom Park
p2.js:47 Magic Kingdom Park
p2.js:50 Magic Kingdom Park



p2.js:42 Epcot
p2.js:47 Epcot
p2.js:50 Magic Kingdom Park
```

So the selectedValue and svalue are updating correctly, but not locationSelected.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find; is what `svalue` returns in line with how `.find` is described?

Comment: I must just be reading .find wrong then? So its just supposed to find the first element in the array, rather than the first object that has the value that I am trying to search for?

Comment: It finds the first element in the array where the function returns true. What does your function return?

Comment: The svalue function? It is returning the value of what is selected in the drop down menu, which is what I am looking for. As seen on line 47 in the last part of the code section.

Comment: @user2951723: Your svalue must have an argument, which represents the array element being passed to the function, and should return true if the element matches the criterion (el.description === selected.value).

Answer (score 0):

The find method takes an argument which represents an element of the array being searched and returns true iff the element matches the relevant criteria (in your case, that element.description == selected.value). The way it works is that `find` calls the provided function for each array element, passing it in and getting the result. As soon as that result is true (or "truthy"), it returns the element. So try this:

```
var svalue = function(el){
    return el.description === selected.value;
}
```